# Norm of homogeneous Besov space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Suppose $f \in (\dot B_{2}^{-r,\infty})^n$. We are discussing in the context of $\mathbb R^n$, then what is the norm of $f$ in this Besov space?
I looked up the notes and they are given in a vague way by saying the interpolation space, which confused me. I was wondering whether there is an explicit way to denote the norm.